# Where is this sql query contain syntax error?

Tags: mysql

Cant understand where is here syntax error?

```
INSERT INTO `playlist_playlistentry` VALUES (playlist_id, media_id, order_by, added)
SELECT (699086, `playlist_playlistentry`.`media_id`, `playlist_playlistentry`.`order` order_by, `playlist_playlistentry`.`added`)
FROM `playlist_playlistentry`
WHERE `playlist_playlistentry`.`playlist_id` = 371390
```

The error in workbench looks like:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 699086, `playlist_playlistentry`.`media_id`, `playlist_playlistentry`.`or' at line 2
```

Comment: you have SELECT after values. is it supposed to be one query or two?

Comment: @galchen: This is an insert command where the source of the values is not hard-coded, but dynamical, that's the select clause for.

Comment: what comes after VALUES is the values that you insert into the tables. you need to put VALUES after the list of the columns

Comment: Yes, but Pol didn't know the syntax.

Comment: And he obviously wanted to get the values using the select statement, the text in the () after VALUES contain column names which is illegal in insert statements, so, intuitively some people, including myself figured out the purpose of the code. The purpose of the code was to insert dynamically values, using a select clause into a table. In this scenario VALUES is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a select to get the values, but from your query I think you want to put the column list. The correct syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO `playlist_playlistentry`(playlist_id, media_id, order_by, added)
SELECT 699086, `playlist_playlistentry`.`media_id`, `playlist_playlistentry`.`order` order_by, `playlist_playlistentry`.`added`
FROM `playlist_playlistentry`
WHERE `playlist_playlistentry`.`playlist_id` = 371390
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop the VALUES keyword. It is not used when inserting from a select statement.

```
INSERT INTO `playlist_playlistentry` 
    (playlist_id, media_id, order_by, added)
    SELECT 699086, `playlist_playlistentry`.`media_id`, `playlist_playlistentry`.`order` order_by, `playlist_playlistentry`.`added`
        FROM `playlist_playlistentry`
        WHERE `playlist_playlistentry`.`playlist_id` = 371390
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO `playlist_playlistentry` (playlist_id, ...)
```

Also remove the parenthesis from the `SELECT part`:

```
SELECT (699086, ... )
```

into:

```
SELECT 699086, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a backtic character instead of an apostrophe `'` ? It also looks like you have extraneous parens around the `SELECT` column list.